# How to tile two excel workbooks horizontaly using C# code

Tags: c#, excel

How to tile two Excel workbook horizontally using c# code (in Excel View->Arrange all). Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA you would do it like this:

```
Sub TileWindows()
Application.Windows.arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlArrangeStyleTiled
End Sub
```

([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff822501%28v=office.14%29.aspx))

and in C# I believe it should be like this if you use the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel assembly (microsoft.office.tools.excel.dll):

```
private void TileApplicationWindows()
{
    this.Application.Windows.Arrange(Excel.XlArrangeStyle.xlArrangeStyleTiled,
        missing, missing, missing);
}
```

where **Application** refers to a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application object.